# React native m3u radio player

Tags: react-native, expo, mp3, internet-radio, m3u

I am trying to make a radio streaming app using react native but it doesn't work.

I tried expo-av with Expo CLI, and react-native-radio-player, react-native-video from react native CLI

all of them work well with mp3 and mp4 extensions but don't work with m3u extension..

`RadioPlayer.radioURL('https://radio.therockeg.com/clv_64.m3u');`

I use https://icecast.org/ for the radio streaming, any help?

Comment: I've had best experiences using https://react-native-track-player.js.org/ for streaming internet radio. It also allows you read live metadata for the station

Answer (score 2):

`m3u` is just a text format with a list of sources inside, you can read this data on your app side, extract sources and play it with any player you prefer.